# How to avoid hardcoding in java

Tags: java

I have read many articles on avoiding hardcoding in java. But could not get clear idea on how to apply it on my requirement.After doing some research am asking this question. Below is my code snippet. In that I want to avoid the hardcoding of the path name in `Process pr = rt.exec()` .Any suggestions on how to do it?

```
public class StartUp {

String executable = getStringValue("executable.run");
    String filein = getStringValue("incoming.file");
    String params1 = getStringValue("executable.params1");
    String params2 = getStringValue("executable.params2");
    String log = getStringValue("log.file");
String ss = "Started";
public String startCommand() throws IOException, InterruptedException{



Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
//Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\server\\rd.exe -a C:\\file.lic -z[+] // C:\\File\\log.txt");

Process pr = rt.exec(executable+" "+params1+" "+filein+" "+params2+" "+log);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader 
(pr.getInputStream()));

String line=null;
StringBuffer start= new StringBuffer();
    while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                start.append("ServerStarted" + line + "\n");
        System.out.println(line);
}

int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);
return line;



//return start.toString();
}
private static String getStringValue(String string) {
    return string;

}
}
```

Comment: What needs to vary under what circumstances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have severals things to try:

**java PROPERTIES**

```
private Properties _properties;

private void init(){
     _properties = new Properties();
     InputStream configurationFileIS = PropertiesConfigurationHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CONFIGURATION_FILE);
     _properties.load(configurationFileIS);
}

public String getStringValue(String path) {
    return _properties.getProperty(path);
}
```

and the properties file will be similar to

```
an.element.to.be.configured.like.a.path=/dev/null
```

**But you can also use SPRING CONTEXT**

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>WEB-INF/classes/config/properties/database.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:config/properties/database.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

and the elements inside database.properties will be accessed that way

```
"${jdbc.username}"
```

--

**For your concrete problem.**

You can create a file constants.properties

```
executable.run=C:\\server\\rd.exe
incoming.file=C:\\file.lic
executable.params=-z
log.file=C:\\File\\log.txt
```

and then after the init you do calls to getStringValue:

```
String executable = getStringValue("executable.run");
String filein = getStringValue("incoming.file");
String params = getStringValue("executable.params");
String log = getStringValue("log.file");
```

Then you can do the `rt.exec` and instead of using hardcoded strings, you can use the ones you retrieve before.

Comment: @Dave Newton: Thanks for the quick reply.My actual need is if you notice in my question Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\server\\rd.exe -a C:\\file.lic -z[+] 
C:\\File\\log.txt");Am starting an executable file rd.exe based on a lic file located in C:\ and am storing those details in a log file located in C:\File.
All these things I want to avoid hardcoding.

Comment: Thanks I think this is going to work. But how do I give these in rt.exec

Comment: `rt.exec(executable+" "+filein+" "+params+" "+log);`

Comment: :Thanks again. i did the modifications but am getting below exception.I edited the question above wiht modifications,please let me know if am going wrong somewhere..java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "executable.run": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042) at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615) at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448) at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:345) at  Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 3):

- Use a system property, e.g., `-Dpath=...` and `System.getProperty("path");`
- Use a config file
- Pass it in on the command line
- Get it from JNDI
- Etc.

In other words, there are a ton of different ways, the best depends on your actual needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just assign the string to a well named `private final static String`. That way the code becomes more readable (and easier to update if you need to change it later.

```
private final static String rtCommand = ""C:\\server\\rd.exe -a C:\\file.lic -z[+] C:\\File\\log.txt";//or something more smartly named. You would know what to name it.
....
Process pr = rt.exec(rtCommand);
```

Comment: Yup I did try this way already but it does recognize the string. May be because I have number of paths in a single String.

Comment: @user2821894 That is odd, it should work just the same. I think you did something wrong, maybe a typo.